# Is there a whole number $x$ so that $2^x+x^2=555555555$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a last-digit algebra problem.

I've tried making tables for $x$ starting from $1$ to prove that the last digit of $2^x+x^2$ is never equal to $5$ but I don't see a pattern.

Comment: @Integrand Careful with this. Note that $2^{11}+11^2$ ends with a $9$ while none of the previous do. If you have modulo arithmetic in mind, note that $2^x$ is more complicated.

Comment: The values of $2^x$ modulo 5 cycle through the sequence $1, 2, 4, 3$ and the quadratic residues modulo 5 are $0$, $1$, and $4$, so if $5 \mid 2^x + x^2$, $2^x$ is congruent to $0$ or $2$  modulo 4 and hence $2^x + x^2$ is even. So Integrand's idea works, but I suspect it involves things the OP doesn't know yet (like the fact the ,multiplicative group of integers modulo 5 is cyclic).

Comment: @RobArthan It works, but you have (modulo $5$) one 4-cycle and one 5-cycle, you can't stop checking at $10$, as if everything was repeating modulo $10$. I'm pretty sure Integrand didn't pay attention that the simple approach works with polynomials but not with exponentials, hence my comment. With Fermat's little theorem, however, no problem.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: I said that the idea works, by which I meant "the idea can be turned into a proof with quite a bit of extra work", but saying it like that would have made my comment too long. $\ddot{\smile}$. Certainly, my proof would be better motivated by looking at the patterns for $x = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.

Answer (score 3):

If such $x$ exists, it must certainly be $\ge 2$. Then $2^x$ is a multiple of $4$, whereas $55\ldots55 = 20\cdot (\ldots)+15$ is $1$ less than a multiple of $4$. But $x^2$ is either a multiple of $4$ or one more than a multiple of $4$.